# What values can CAAction's runActionForKey:object:arguments: arguments take?

Tags: ios, macos, core-animation, quartz-core

The `CAAction` protocol seems a bit poorly documented, and rarely commented on in books and blogs. The arguments for its sole method, `runActionForKey:object:arguments:`, are a bit mysterious. In my experience, the "object" argument always seems to be a `CALayer`, and the "arguments" dictionary is always `nil`.

It seems like the protocol might have been designed to be used in multiple places in Core Animation, otherwise why not define the type of the layer argument, and why have the extra dictionary that is never used? But as far as I can tell, it is only used with `CALayer`. Is that correct? Does anyone have any examples where the above conclusions are not true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `CAAction` has not been used in any other APIs. When the protocol was designed it was left generic in case it became useful later, but nothing came up.

It’s simple to define and invoke your own layer actions. A contrived example could be to dispatch a “mouseDown” action into the hit-tested layer passing some kind of event-specific data:

```
CALayer *layer = myHitTest(…);
[[layer actionForKey:@“mouseDown”]
 runActionForKey:@“mouseDown” object:layer arguments:@{…}];
```

Here you’d not want the action to add an animation, so would implement the `CAAction` protocol on the class that handles the events, then put an instance of that class in the layer's `actions` dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

The only actual use of CAAction is as the basis of implicit animation - that is, it is at the heart of the mechanism by which an expression like

```
myLayer.position = // ... whatever ...
```

is magically able to animation the layer's change in position (assuming it is not the primary underlying layer of a UIView).

For a complete explanation of the action search mechanism, see my book:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_actions_2

Comment: Thanks, @Matt. I have your book, and I'd already read that. (Been spending a lot of time in that chapter this past week!) I understand how to hook into the search mechanism; I was just trying to understand the design and usages of the protocol, given those oddities I mentioned. I'm created a wrapper for creating `CAAction`s using a block, and wanted to simplify the interface if possible.

Comment: Thanks also @matt, but I think there are two errors / omissions in Ch 17: Hooking Into the Action Search.  Returning Nil does not cause the animation to be disabled per-se, the search just continues, per [1.2](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/ReactingtoLayerChanges/ReactingtoLayerChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH7-SW2).  Returning NSNull does abort the search though (1.3).  And second, triggers can also be on any KVC property, even if those that are not themselves animatable (same link).

Comment: @chrisco I think you'll find the search is correctly described in the current edition of the book. Thanks for the point about the use of KVC to trigger the search; I'll see about adding that if there's yet another edition!

Comment: @chrisco OK, I now understand that setting a property on a layer is _always_ translated into `setValue:forKey:` and it is this that triggers `actionForKey:`. Thank you for clarifying this for me! Have you an example where hooking to the action search for an arbitrary `setValue:forKey:` is useful?

Comment: @chrisco I thought of an example! Thanks again.

Comment: @matt  Just saw your comment now.  I did go down a rabbit hole with a task that required moving a sub layer opposite the main layer.  It's too long for a comment, so I'll track down your email from your book site, etc.  The gist though, is that I tapped into actionForKey to see if the main layer was to be animated (my code handled animated and non animated cases), and either move or animate the sub layer accordingly - I needed to keep them in sync in all cases, but only sub-animate if the parent was animating.  Cheers -c